# Operate on neighbor elements in RDD in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

As I have a collection:

```
List(1, 3,-1, 0, 2, -4, 6)
```

It's easy to make it sorted as:

```
List(-4, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 6)
```

Then I can construct a new collection by compute 6 - 3, 3 - 2, 2 - 1, 1 - 0, and so on like this:

```
for(i <- 0 to list.length -2) yield {
    list(i + 1) - list(i)
}
```

and get a vector:

```
Vector(3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3)
```

That is, I want to make the next element minus the current element.

But how to implement this in RDD on Spark?

I know for the collection:

```
List(-4, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 6)
```

There will be some partitions of the collection, each partition is ordered, can I do the similar operation on each partition and collect results on each partition together?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most efficient solution is to use `sliding` method:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(1, 3,-1, 0, 2, -4, 6))
  .sortBy(identity)
  .sliding(2)
  .map{case Array(x, y) => y - x}
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have something like

```
val seq = sc.parallelize(List(1, 3, -1, 0, 2, -4, 6)).sortBy(identity)
```

Let's create first collection with *index as key* like Ton Torres suggested

```
val original = seq.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)
```

Now we can build collection shifted by one element.

```
val shifted = original.map { case (idx, v) => (idx - 1, v) }.filter(_._1 >= 0)
```

Next we can calculate needed differences ordered by index descending

```
val diffs = original.join(shifted)
      .sortBy(_._1, ascending = false)
      .map { case (idx, (v1, v2)) => v2 - v1 }
```

So

```
 println(diffs.collect.toSeq)
```

shows

```
WrappedArray(3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3)
```

Note that you can skip the `sortBy` step if reversing is not critical.

Also note that for local collection this could be computed much more simple like:

```
val elems = List(1, 3, -1, 0, 2, -4, 6).sorted  

(elems.tail, elems).zipped.map(_ - _).reverse
```

But in case of `RDD` the `zip` method requires each collection should contain equal element count for each partition. So if you would implement `tail` like

```
val tail = seq.zipWithIndex().filter(_._2 > 0).map(_._1)
```

`tail.zip(seq)` would not work since both collection needs equal count of elements for each partition and we have one element for each partition that should travel to previous partition.

Comment: It'll work but is extremely inefficient. You could reduce the cost by using `rangePartitioner` but I doubt it is worth all the fuss.