# Using apache spark to iterate over string

Tags: scala, apache-spark

For example we have the string "abcdabcd"

And we want to count all the pairs (e.g: "ab" or "da") that are available in the string.

So how do we do that in apache spark?

I asked this cause it looks like that the RDD does not support sliding function:

```
rdd.sliding(2).toList
//Count number of pairs in list
//Returns syntax error on first line (sliding)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently it supports `sliding` via [mllib](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions) as shown by zero323 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34155080/210905)

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._

val str = "abcdabcd"

val rdd = sc.parallelize(str)

rdd.sliding(2).map(_.mkString).toLocalIterator.forEach(println)
```

will show

> ab
>   bc
>   cd
>   da
>   ab
>   bc
>   cd

Comment: and how do we count these pairs? Well btw you look like someone who is hunting my scala questions here :)

Comment: @lkn2993 using the classic [word count](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html) approach in `Apache Spark`