# spark (Scala) dataframe filtering (FIR)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Let say I have a dataframe ( stored in scala val as `df`) which contains the data from a csv:

```
time,temperature
0,65
1,67
2,62
3,59
```

which I have no problem reading this from file as a spark dataframe in scala language.

I would like to add a filtered column (by filter I meant signal processing moving average filtering), (say I want to do `(T[n]+T[n-1])/2.0`):

```
time,temperature,temperatureAvg
0,65,(65+0)/2.0
1,67,(67+65)/2.0
2,62,(62+67)/2.0
3,59,(59+62)/2.0
```

(Actually, say for the first row, I want `32.5` instead of `(65+0)/2.0`. I wrote it to clarify the expected 2-time-step filtering operation output)

So how to achieve this? I am not familiar with spark dataframe operation which combine rows iteratively along column...

Answer (score 6):

**Spark 3.1+**

Replace

```
$"time".cast("timestamp")
```

with

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.timestamp_seconds

timestamp_seconds($"time")
```

**Spark 2.0+**

In Spark 2.0 and later it is possible to use `window` function as a input for `groupBy`. It allows you to specify  `windowDuration`, `slideDuration` and `startTime` (offset). It works only with `TimestampType` column but it is not that hard to find a workaround for that. In your case it will require some additional steps to correct for boundaries but general solution can expressed as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{window, avg}

df
    .withColumn("ts", $"time".cast("timestamp"))
    .groupBy(window($"ts", windowDuration="2 seconds", slideDuration="1 second"))
    .avg("temperature")
```

**Spark < 2.0**

If there is a natural way to partition your data you can use window functions as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.mean

val w = Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"time").rowsBetween(-1, 0)

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    (1L, 0, 65), (1L, 1, 67), (1L, 2, 62), (1L, 3, 59)
)).toDF("id", "time", "temperature")

df.select($"*", mean($"temperature").over(w).alias("temperatureAvg")).show

// +---+----+-----------+--------------+                             
// | id|time|temperature|temperatureAvg|
// +---+----+-----------+--------------+
// |  1|   0|         65|          65.0|
// |  1|   1|         67|          66.0|
// |  1|   2|         62|          64.5|
// |  1|   3|         59|          60.5|
// +---+----+-----------+--------------+
```

You can create windows with arbitrary weights using `lead` / `lag` functions:

```
 lit(0.6) * $"temperature" + 
 lit(0.3) * lag($"temperature", 1) +
 lit(0.2) * lag($"temperature", 2)
```

It is still possible without `partitionBy` clause but will be extremely inefficient. If this is the case you won't be able to use `DataFrames`. Instead you can use `sliding` over RDD (see for example [Operate on neighbor elements in RDD in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34146907/1560062)). There is also [spark-timeseries](https://github.com/cloudera/spark-timeseries) package you may find useful.

Comment: Thanks zero! it works pretty well. A related question, what if I want to do filtering instead of `0.5T[n] + 0.5T[n-1]` but want like `0.6T[n] + 0.3T[n-1] + 0.1T[n-2]` where `T[n]` is the temperature at row n?

Comment: Instead of `mean` use `lag` and `lead`.